# Jmeter thread groups interfering with each other

Tags: regex, multithreading, jmeter, http-status-code-401

I have 2 thread groups. Each thread group uses a different Csvdataset (email,password) to sign up a new user and click on different set of pages of a rails website. I take into account the dynamic CSRF token with the Regex extractor.

Since it is the same flow for both thread groups, I use a module controller to avoid code duplication, which contains 2 regex extractors.

A single thread execution for the two thread groups works fine. But when I multithread, I see some pages failing with `401 Unauthorized` error messages and I cannot figure out why.

Could it be the case that the threads are getting mixed up, i.e. threadgroup1-thread2 extracting the regex from threadgroup2-thread5?

Comment: Please do not post one big block of words, with no separation of paragraphs and no formatting. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to format

Comment: can you show your test plan expanded ? thx

Comment: Yes, here is the link - http://prntscr.com/arr0o3.     The ReceiptSubmission and BoostActivation thread groups are the ones sharing the common Login module which contains the Regex extractor. I have confirmed that the problem persists even if I duplicate the code, i.e. without the login module controller

Comment: As a workaround, I disabled the csrf token validation on the rails web server with skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token in the application_controller.rb. Now, the test runs as expected